# Delete multiple occurences of same object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In our collection, there's structure like:

```
Object: //below is object metadata from mongo
    _id
    created_at
    lang
    source
    object: //this is real object data from our db
        id
        created_at
        object_class
```

I ran below query on this collection:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate(
    [
    {
        $match: {
            lang: 'bar', 
            pushed_at:{
            $gte: new ISODate("2015-11-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: new ISODate("2015-11-10T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$object.id",
            occurences: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            occurences: {$gt: 1}
        }
    }
])
```

Which returned:
[image]

It appears that we got duplicate entries in our collection. By duplicate I mean objects with same `Object.object.id`.
I'd like to remove redundant occurences using results from agreggate function I used. **Notice that I don't want to delete anything, just rendundant ones, so above aggregate returns `occurences: 1`**.

How to do this, also using results from aggregation?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. some sample data just enough to produce the desired result and the expected output from that sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try that in the shell :

```
db.foo.aggregate(
    [
    {
        $match: {
            lang: 'bar', 
            pushed_at:{
            $gte: new ISODate("2015-11-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: new ISODate("2015-11-10T00:00:00.000Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$object.id",
            occurences: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            occurences: {$gt: 1}
        }
    }
]).result.forEach(function(x) {
    if(x.occurences > 1) {  
        for(i=0;i<x.occurences - 1;i++) {
            db.foo.remove({"object.id":x._id}, true);
        }
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!

Comment: Sorry for side question but I wonder if, in general, it is possible to call methods like find() on previous query results?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you be more specfic ?

Comment: Let's say that above `aggregate` produces results that I want to filter using another find() method, and in the end do something with them, like: db.col.aggregate(foo).find(using foo).count().

Comment: Oh no i don't think you can do that directly

Comment: Thanks again anyway! :)

Comment: But you can do à batch of if to match multiple conditions in your foreach